# biblatex autolang=other breaks authortitle layout

Tags: biblatex, babel, hyphenation

Here's a MWE for `autolang=other` breaking something with the citation and bibliography layout: you will notice that the author but the first one name aren't capitalized.  To me, it would be alright if none of the author names were and it could be considered as a dirty fix.  But change '`other`' to '`hyphen`' and everything will go alright.  Donno where to report this if not here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,german,french]{babel}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1,dashed=false,backend=biber,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{file.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{file.bib}
@BOOK{binetmag,
  title={Le Magn{\'e}tisme animal : {\'E}tudes sur l'hypnose},
  publisher={l'Harmattan},
  year={2006 [1887]},
  author={Alfred Binet and Charles F{\'e}r{\'e}},
  pages={283 pages},
  langid={french}
}
@BOOK{collinscha,
  title={Changing Order: Replication and Induction in Scientific Practice},
  publisher={University of Chicago Press},
  year={1992 [1985]},
  author={Harry Collins},
  edition={New Edition},
  langid={english}
}

@BOOK{collinsoth,
  title={another book title with same author},
  publisher={na},
  year={9999},
  author={Harry Collins},
  langid={english}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{binetmag}

\cite{collinscha}

\cite{collinsoth}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just issue a

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}{\textsc}
```

in the preamble.

The problem was arising because French, by default, enables small caps for author's last names, English, on the other hand, does no such thing. If the language in the bibliography is switched using `autolang=other` the default language "extras" are also changed, this lead to only the French entry having small caps and not the English ones.

If we redefine `\mkbibnamelast` as above, small caps are always applied to all authors regardless of language.